# Need solution for DIVI wordpress theme error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi-theme

After installing DIVI theme on my localhost XAMPP, it show an warning in top of WP admin area.

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in F:\local_host\htdocs\fiverr-wp\wp-content\themes\Divi\includes\builder\functions.php on line 5941

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Please note this is a WARNING and not error. make sure to turn off debug on wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Comment: is it not create any problem while working on this Theme?

Comment: It does not for me. But you can contact elegantthemes regarding that builder function.